# Android Studio and Lint don't generate an error when an IntDef field is assigned a wrong value

Tags: android, annotations, lint

Here is my code:

Const.kt

```
package sample.com.sample_app

object Const {
    const val NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD = 1
    const val NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST = 2
}
```

NavigationMode.kt

```
package sample.com.sample_app

import android.support.annotation.IntDef
import java.lang.annotation.Retention
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.SOURCE

@Retention(SOURCE)
@IntDef(Const.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST, Const.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD)
annotation class NavigationMode
```

OtherAct.kt

```
package sample.com.sample_app

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity

class OtherAct : AppCompatActivity() {

    @NavigationMode
    private var a: Int = 12

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        a = 34
    }
}
```

No error or warning from Android Studio or `./gradlew lint`

My environment:

```
buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"
kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it works only for function's parameters and not for the property itself

Comment: This answer is still correct. I was trying to do this today in my project. I ended up using an enum instead.